# Accessing data from a json array in python

Tags: python, json

One of my responses looks like,

```
{
    "password": [
        "Ensure that this field has atleast 5 and atmost 50 characters"
    ]
}
```

And I am trying to fetch the string inside password.How I can get it.

Below is the code which I am trying

```
key = json.loads(response['password'])
print(key[0]),
```

But it says 'string indices must be integers, not str'

Comment: is this in python?

Comment: In java or ????

Comment: I am trying in python

Comment: Please provide the script language in the tags  to help you with your problem ..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error message is correct.

```
key = json.loads(response['password'])
print(key[0]),
```

The format of `json` is string.  You need to convert the string of a json object to python dict before you can access it.

i.e.: `loads(string)` before `info[key]`

```
key = json.loads(response)['password']
print(key[0])
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually the json will be a string and you will try and deserialise it into a object graph (which in python are typically are made up of maps and arrays).

so assuming your response is actually a string (eg that was retrieved from a HTTP request/endpoint) then you deserialise it with json.loads (the function is basically load from string), then you've got a map with a 'password' key, that is an array, so grab the first element from it.

```
import json

resp = '{ "password": [ "Ensure that this field has atleast 5 and atmost 50 characters" ] }'
print json.loads(resp)['password'][0]
```